# ReactJs: Input value doesn't change because due to using Array.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-binding

This is the table body:

```
<tbody>
  {this.state.composantInformation.map(composantInformation => {
    return (
      <tr key={composantInformation.id.toString()}>
        <td>{composantInformation.nom_composant}</td>
        <td>{composantInformation.categorie}</td>
        <td>{composantInformation.description}</td>
        <td>{composantInformation.ref}</td>
        <td>
          <NumericInput
            min={0}
            max={100}
            value={composantInformation.qte}
            onChange={this.onQuantiteChange}
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  })}
</tbody>;
```

This is the state:

```
this.state = {
  produitInformation: [],
  composantInformation: [],
  produitId: 0,
  produitQte: 0
};
```

This is where the Backend API request is made:

```
componentDidMount() {
  getProduitDataFromDB()
    .then(result => {
      this.setState({
        produitInformation: result.data
      });
    })
    .catch(error => console.error("(1) Outside error:", error));
}
```

And this is the result:
[image]

In the last column, when I click on Increment/Decrement, the value gets increased and then goes back to 0.
I believe this has something to do with the fact that I am using `map` to display the table data.

```
{
  this.state.produitInformation.map(produitInformation => {
    return (
      <tr
        key={produitInformation.id.toString()}
        produitid={produitInformation.id.toString()}
        onClick={this.onTableRowClick}
      >
        <td>{produitInformation.nom_produit}</td>
        <td>{produitInformation.prix}</td>
        <td>{produitInformation.categorie}</td>
        <td>{produitInformation.description}</td>
        <td>
          <NumericInput
            min={0}
            max={100}
            value={produitInformation.qte}
            tablerow={5}
            onChange={this.onQuantiteChange}
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
}
```

Since the `value` inside `NumericInput` is not associated directly with a state value. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the specific array element where the increase has happened, so need two parameters one to identify the element using id, and another is value

```
onQuantiteChange(id, value){

const newData = this.state.produitInformation.map(d => {
if(d.id === id) {
return {...d, qte: value}
}
return d;
})
this.setState({produitInformation: newData})
}
```

Also change

```
<td>
                            <NumericInput
                              min={0}
                              max={100}
                              value={produitInformation.qte}
                              tablerow={5}
                              onChange={(val) => this.onQuantiteChange(produitInformation.id, val)}
                            />
                          </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make a state for the NumericInput value for and onChange on that NumericInput you need to set the new state inorder for the value to change